# How to have multiple css clipped sprites?

Tags: css, image, sprite, clip

I want to have a row of images, which I have assembled into one with pnmcat -lr.  I don't want an image map, because the pieces get exchanged for highlighting.  I have meaningful images, so I want `<img>` rather than background.

Promising examples seem to be http://css-tricks.com/css-sprites-with-inline-images/ and http://1plusdesign.com/articles/css-clip-property-inline-image-sprites/.  The latter even shows some html, with three imgs in a row.

But when downloading the demo, it only uses them separately.  And when I paste in the div from demo 1, I get the same result as whatever I try on my page: they are all on top of one another rather than in a row.  I have tried wrapping them separately, putting a width on the wrapper, positioning it relatively, nothing works...

Btw. both authors use two classes simultaneously.  I there any reason for this?  Given that there is a wrapper, the class that is the same for all images could be a nested css, and then the other class could be an id (if it's used only once), right?

```
.wrapper img {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
}
#sad { clip: rect(0 128px 128px 0); }
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't show enough of your code to provide a definite answer.

If by "on top of one another", you mean they're all in the same place, then my guess is that your wrappers don't have the `position: relative` property.  So, the images are all positioned relative to the container of the wrappers rather than directly relative to the wrappers themselves.  If they're set to `top: 0; left: 0`, then being on top of each other is the correct behavior.  Use `position: relative;` on the `.wrapper` class, but also keep in mind that the positioning of the image is related to the clipping of the image.

If "on top of one another" means stacked vertically, then my guess is that the wrappers need to `float: left` to sit in a row.  This still has nothing to do with the clipping.

Comment: The code is that of the two examples, each time with three different imgs next to one another.  And yes on top means covering one another.  Before I try your hints I'll check what this one does better: http://www.cssplay.co.uk/menu/clip_gallery.html

Comment: @Daniel, your code can't be exactly as it is in the two examples you gave because the demo pages for those examples don't have the problem you've described. http://css-tricks.com/examples/CSSClip/ & http://1plusdesign.com/wp-content/themes/1plusdesign/tutorials/css-clip/css-clip.html

Answer (score 0):

I wondered why the sprite clippers insist on putting a corresponding negative left or top.  I shouldn't have accepted this as a mystery, because it is exactly the key to understanding: Clip has a strange geometry, the whole picture is there, but only the rect is visible at its unchanged(!!!) location.  The img tag however is a box only around the rect.

Now with absolute pos and negative left I would pull all the rects to the same position.  Instead, what I want is to move them even a little more right to get gaps.  With that the tab bar in http://makepp.sourceforge.net/ works like a marvel in all browsers.